# Symfony2 error when injecting Donctrine in controller

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to enject doctrine in controller:

This is my services:

```
services:
    default_controller:
        class:     Catalog\WebBundle\Controller\DefaultController
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

Controller:

```
public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
{
}
```

**CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception ErrorException: "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Catalog\WebBundle\Controller\DefaultController::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in /home/katalogas/domains/example.com/public_html/app/cache/dev/classes.php on line 2783 and defined in /home/katalogas/domains/example.com/public_html/src/Catalog/WebBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 23" at /home/katalogas/domains/example.com/public_html/src/Catalog/WebBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 23 
    Context: {"exception":"Object(ErrorException)"}**

I'm sure that my service.yml is loaded, because when I make typo - get parse error.

Comment: I think you are already injecting an instance of EntityManager, therefore $this->em = $em should be enough

Comment: @np87 noo problem is not here, I can remove that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably set the controller for your **route** using the controller notation e.g: `SomeBundle:SomeController:SomeAction` you have to use the service notation in your routing.i.e:

```
# when defining your route in yml
...
{ _controller: default_controller:someAction ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this syntax it works.

```
    arguments:
        - @doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
```